# sql long operation connection close

Tags: sql, azure, ssms

I have a problem with a long running Operation.

**What I try:**
I try to create an non clustered index on a very huge table.

**My problem:**
The Operation runs fine for nearly one hour. But than SSMS shows an error "Error: 0, Connection closed by remote host". And no index is created. :(

How can I perform my really long taking index creation without connection lost?

**Settings:**

SQL-ManagmentStudio 2012

Azure SQL-DB

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_StringData_TimeStamp_ID] ON [dbo].[StringData]
(
    [DCDistributionBoxID] ASC,
    [TimeStamp] DESC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = ON)
```

Comment: I think this basically Azure killing a long query, we have exactly the same problem. The only thought I had was taking the database up to Premium and then run it and then take it back down afterwards. We cannot do that currently because we are using the Premium setup already on another database.

Comment: Could you perhaps 'duplicate' the table structure - place the index in the new, then insert the data and flip the two around to avoid the long running index generation?